# Returning most occurring element in row of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with a column containing strings like this:

```
percentage | name
-----------------
122        | a
122        | b
122        | b
122        | c
```

Now I want to return the most frequent name, in this example 'b'. I know I can do this by iterating over the rows and keeping a counter, but there must be a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the `index` of [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) which sorts on count:

```
In [85]:
df['name'].value_counts().index[0]

Out[85]:
'b'
```

output from `value_counts`:

```
In [86]:
df['name'].value_counts()

Out[86]:
b    2
c    1
a    1
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Ah, didn't know that value_counts sorted on count, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and `argmax`:

```
In [221]: df.name.value_counts().argmax()
Out[221]: 'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html) or [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) what is same as [`argmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.argmax.html):

```
print df.name.value_counts().first_valid_index()
#b
print df.name.value_counts().idxmax()
#b
```

**Timings**:

These timings are going to be very dependent on the size of s as well as the number (and position) of values:

```
In [145]: %timeit df.name.value_counts().argmax()
The slowest run took 5.25 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 322 µs per loop

In [146]: %timeit df.name.value_counts().index[0]
The slowest run took 6.32 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 275 µs per loop

In [147]: %timeit df.name.value_counts().first_valid_index()
The slowest run took 5.43 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 292 µs per loop

In [148]: %timeit df.name.value_counts().idxmax()
The slowest run took 5.30 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 321 µs per loop
```